# How would I convert this ternary expression into if else statements?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I'm trying to find a simpler way of converting this ternary expression into if else expression.

```
Account account = selection != 1 ? (Account)customer.Saving : (Account)customer.Checking;
```

Comment: `Account account; if (selection != 1) { account = (Account)customer.Saving } else { account = (Account)customer.Checking; }` ... but why?

Comment: You sure you are the one coding this?

Comment: Just was curious of the equivalent expression.

Answer (score 0):

you can write:

```
Account account;
if(selection != 1)
{
    account= (Account)customer.Saving
}
else{
    account= (Account)customer.Checking;
}
```

Comment: why downvote? i don't think i have written anything wrong. please explain who ever has downvoted

Comment: Answer is correct, plus 1. The reason I can think of the down-vote is that the question is definitely a dupe and of low quality. If you answer the question then you are promoting the questioner and future visitors to ask such questions.